# Is there some Unix util that will allow me to grep multiple files with little typing?

Tags: unix, text, find, grep

Right now I do this a lot:

```
find * | grep py$ | xargs grep foo
```

I recall there is some util that does this with way less typing, but which?

UPDATE: I prefer to use the Bash shell if possible.

Comment: I like how every single answer is longer than the OP...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I love [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/):

Which would you rather type?

`$ grep pattern $(find . -type f | grep -v '\.svn')`

`$ ack pattern`

Answer (score 4):

You may find your shell helps you. For instance, in [zsh](http://www.zsh.org), you can do

```
grep foo **/*.py
```

provided the number of .py files doesn't exceed the maximum number of arguments allowed for a command (64k?). Note you can qualify the file globbing e.g.

```
grep foo **/*.py(mh-5)
```

which will give you everything modified in the last 5 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

Comment: yeah, ack is a great replacement for grep (at least for programmers)

Answer (score 2):

zsh has recursive globbing, so you can do

```
grep foo **/*.py
```

Look ma, no find :)

**UPDATE: Oh, also if you do something a lot it doesn't hurt to alias or write a function for it of course**

Comment: Given zsh's ability to do this, I barely have to mess with find's arcane syntax

Answer (score 2):

It's called grep *wink* :-)

All py in current directory

```
grep -R foo *.py
```

All files in current and any sub-directory

```
grep -R foo .
```

Comment: +1: -R is standard on most UNIX commands to also scan subdirectories recursively.

Comment: Don't you need to quote or escape your globbing ? Otherwise the shell will expand this in the current directory ?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -r --include='*.py' foo *
```

Comment: That's an odd definition of the word "less"

Comment: Yeah.  Less chaining feels like less worry to me, but OP didn't ask for less worry, he asked for less typing.  Edited to something actually shorter.  Slightly.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec grep -H foo '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Tip: end your exec expression with a '+' instead of ';', which will make find send all matching files to a single grep process instead of forking off a new one for each matching file. Much more efficient that way.

Answer (score 0):

I use something very much like your find/grep pair a lot, although with even more conditions -- excluding files in .svn directories, for example.  I do this so much I just made scripts around these invocations, so I can call "src-grep ..." and have it do basically what you're doing here.  (Then I added an optional extension for a number of context lines to pass to the grep -C flag, if supplied, and a separate version to grep the results for definition statements.)

This is more useful and faster than recursive grep for me.